# What types of archaea have been found in animals?

Tags: microbiology

I am curious as to the species or "types" of archaea that have been found to reside within animals symbiotically. One of the only ones I can think of off the top of my head are [methanogens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanogen), which live in the gut of ruminants for example.

Answer (score 7):

Humans:

A pioneering study using 16S RNA primers found only *Methanobrevibacter smithii* in the human intestine.

> Eckburg PB *et al*. (2005) Diversity of the human intestinal microbial flora. Science 308 1635-1638

In a recent review there is a comprehensive Table of archaea found in humans (this includes non-intestinal flora):

> Dridi B *et al*. (2011) Archea as emerging organisms in complex human microbiomes. Anaerob2 17: 56-63

Much of the work that is catalogued by Dridi *et al*. is repeated identifications of Methanobacteriales (*Methanobrevibacter smithii*, *Methanosphaera stadtmanae* and *Methanobrevibacter oralis*), but there are others from the Thermoplasmateles, the Halobacteriales and the Sulfolobales, plus some that are thought to be members of unknown archaeal orders.